# Plotting training and Cross-validation error for Lasso using Scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a lasso on a dataset. I used scikit-learn Lasso option. This is the code I used:

```
#Running Lasso On Gdpdataset: 
from sklearn import linear_model 
lasso_gdp=linear_model.LassoCV(max_iter=2000,cv=10,normalize=False)
lasso_gdp.fit(Gdp_train,Gdp_Y)
lasso_gdp.alpha_
scores_gdp=np.zeros((100,1))
scores_gdp[:,0]=np.mean(lasso_gdp.mse_path_,axis=1)
scores_gdp=np.sort(scores_gdp)
lasso_gdp.coef_
```

While lasso.alpha_ and lasso_coef_ gives me the cross-validated alpha and final weight vector, I am looking to plot the MSE of each alpha value(i used default parameter for alpah(100) on the training and the cross-validated set which lasso uses. As of now I am not sure what observation it chose for cross-validation as I simply used the cv=10 option in the lasso method.

Could someone help how to get those two curves for each alpha value?

Comment: You just extracted the validation set error. I'm not sure why you sorted it, though. There is currently no way to get the test set error I think.
This is just KFold cross-validation.

Comment: Yes the scores would have the validation error for each value of alpha. I sorted it to have the least MSE on top. 

But how can i get the corresponding training error. I want to plot the training error and validation error for each value of alpha

Comment: Sorry typo above. There is no way to currently get the training set error.

Comment: Ok Got that. Just one last question. How to get the test error MSE? Like if I have a test set, and I run est.predict function, do I need to calculate MSE by writing a formula or is there an attribute _mse which gives us the MSE of that?

Comment: You can use ``lasso_gdp.score(X_test, y_test)`` but that will actually give you the r2 score. You can use ``mean_squared_error(y_test, lasso_gdp.predict(X_test))`` though. see http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error